# Story where a traumatised soldier vanishes from a hospital

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Story where a traumatised soldier in a hospital vanishes. ‘Experts’ don't understand that poets did this all the time and not a poet can be found anywhere. The story was in English. Perhaps it was by  Asimov.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is extremely terse and  benefit greatly from you going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lone wolf or beserker behaviour of young men in an a very authoritarian society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189184/lone-wolf-or-beserker-behaviour-of-young-men-in-an-a-very-authoritarian-society) - the comment by OP sounds very enthusiastic, and the answer is almost definitely it. Sounds like we'd gain to dupe-close and redirect people to @JohnRennie's superior answer there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Alfred Bester's [Disappearing Act](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40430).

It ends:

> He waited for them to find a poet, not understanding the endless
> delay, the fruitless search, not understanding why Bradley Scrim laughed and laughed and laughed at this final, fatal disappearance.

Comment: Wasn't a Twilight Zone episode based on this? I know that's a little off-topic, but I remember there was an episode about three USAF astronauts that made it in a wreck and went to the base hospital. Then they ended up disappearing one by one with people not having any memory of their existence.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan it's similar, but IMHO the point of the Bester story is that the country is so gunned up and focused on things that directly benefit the war effort, that poetry and other things that they are supposed to be defending have vanished.  I don't remember that theme from the TV show.

Comment: Thanks Organic Marble. That was quick.