# Story Involving Personal Universes/Realities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can someone help determine the title and/or author of this science fiction story? It is from the 1950s to the 1970s. I probably read it in an anthology. It has the following plot (some details may be inexact since I read it almost that long ago):

During a future war, some of the patients at a military hospital are disappearing and later reappearing. It turns out that, due to the extreme mental stress of the war, each has acquired the ability to escape into his or her own reality/pocket universe, for a while, separate from the reality of the war. The general in charge calls in a physicist to investigate, who recommends that a psychologist be called in, who in turn recommends that they call in a philosopher. A philosopher is finally found in a dungeon and dragged in. He tells the general that they need a poet in order to investigate the phenomenon. The general orders a poet to be summoned and after a long wait, he is told that they could not find a poet, and the philosopher gloats in triumph at proving that the general has managed to eradicate poetry from the world. The End!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you thinking of "[Disappearing Act](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40430)" (1953) by Alfred Bester?

The story takes place during a war where a computer has helped train everyone into every necessary specialty for waging the war; so many of this type of technician, so many mechanics, etc.  Then recuperating soldiers start disappearing, and they perform an ever more esoteric search for the reason, culminating in a search for a poet, only to discover that in their entire society not one person has been trained as a poet.

The soldiers disappear:

> “N-No, sir,” Dimmock looked shamefaced. “I don’t know how to tell you this, General Carpenter. I... We lock them up because of the real mystery. They... Well, they disappear.”
>
> “They what?”
>
> “They disappear, sir. Vanish. Right before your eyes.”
>
> “The hell you say.”
>
> “I do say, sir. They’ll be sitting on a bed or standing around. One minute you see them, the next minute you don’t. Sometimes there’s two dozen in Ward T. Other times none. They disappear and reappear without rhyme or reason. That’s why we’ve got the ward locked, General Carpenter. In the entire history of combat and combat injury there’s never been a case like this before. We don’t know how to handle it.”

They call in a bunch of experts including, finally a historian:

> The first five experts were easy to draft away from other war departments. All America was a tool chest of hardened and sharpened specialists. But there was trouble locating a first-class historian until the Federal Penitentiary co-operated with the army and released Dr. Bradley Scrim from his twenty years at hard labour. Dr. Scrim was acid and jagged. He had held the chair of Philosophic History at a Western university until he spoke his mind about the war for the American Dream. That got him twenty years hard.

It is Dr. Scrim who requests a poet:

> “No, I cannot. I’m a historian. I’m non-creative, so it’s beyond me. You need a poet... a man who understands the creation of dreams. From creating dreams on paper it oughtn’t to be too difficult to take the step to creating dreams in actuality.”
>
> “ A poet? Are you serious ?”
>
> “Certainly, I’m serious. Don’t you know what a poet is? You’ve been telling us for five years that this war is being fought to save the poets.”
>
> “Don’t be facetious, Scrim. I-”
>
> “Send a poet into Ward T. He’ll learn how they do it. He’s the only man who can. A poet is half doing it, anyway. Once he learns, he can teach us; but the poet is the only man who can interpret between those shock cases and your experts.”

But there are no more poets:

> Carpenter snapped up his intercom. “ Send me a poet,” he said.
>
> He waited, and waited... and waited... while America sorted feverishly through its two hundred and ninety millions of hardened and sharpened experts, its specialized tools to defend the American Dream of beauty and poetry and the Better Things in Life. He waited for them to find a poet, not understanding the endless delay, the fruitless search; not understanding why Bradley Scrim laughed and laughed at this final, fatal disappearance.

You can read the entire story in the [November 1954 issue](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_029v10_1954-11/page/n57/mode/2up) of *New Worlds Science Fiction* at the Internet Archive.